# Can't read file names with : on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using a PDF viewer on react-native, some **files without : can be opened** but other **files with : won't open** and will return `No content provider`.

Is there a way to read locally stored files with : on it's name on react-native?

For example, this kind of file path

```
const filenameWithSpace = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/somwhere/foo foo Nov 21, 2018 12:16:04 PM.pdf'
```

I already tried `encodeURIComponent` and `encodeURI` but it didn't work.

**Update:**
The problem on the filename was actually the : character not the spaces.

Comment: Hey kcNeko, have you tried adding %20 wherever you need a space in the url?

Comment: which plugin you are using to view pdf files?

Comment: @GrandIQ I already tried replacing all spaces with %20 don't it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @Justcode I'm working with react-native-pdf :)

Comment: Silly question, but have you attempted to try this with a different browser?

Comment: Have you got it solved? @kcNeko

Comment: @GrandIQ not yet :( web browser on the other hand wont also do.

Comment: Not familiar with triple forward slashes, does that mean something specific in terms of directory step backs? 'file:///stor'

Comment: @GrandIQ sorry I'm not a directory guru so I cant explain it :(

Comment: @kcNeko Alright I understand. Just to be sure, your other files have the same file path and work correct?

Comment: @GrandIQ yes, if i have a file whose name is "foo.pdf", it will work like wonders.

Comment: Alright well I tried my best, definitely staring this I want to know how you resolved it!

Comment: @GrandIQ Sorry, somehow the : character was actually the problem not the spaces. Question updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If space in file uri this will fail.

```
var base64data = await RNFS.readFile( res.uri, 'base64').then(res => { return res });
```

Replace with this line

```
var result = res.uri.split("%20").join("\ ");
var base64data = await RNFS.readFile( result, 'base64').then(res => { return res });
```

This will work

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using '\' (backslash)?

Please let me know if this works.

```
var str = "file:///storage/emulated/0/somwhere/foo foo Nov 21, 2018 12:16:04 PM.pdf";
    var result = str.split(" ").join("\ "); // added '\'
    console.log('Result',result);
```

*Snippet copied from answer provided by Vishal Vaghasiya*

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question and it seems like spaces on file names are okay but not the : character :(

Comment: tricky one though.. Good to hear that your issue is solved :)

Comment: It's not really solved but pointed out who the real culprit is XD

Comment: Thanks @HungrySoul your solution have worked for me so far in ios. i will check it further.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to explain the whole process of the app.

The return from database has something like this

```
{file: "//storage/emulated/0/somwhere/foo foo Nov 21, 2018 12:16:04 PM.pdf"}
```

which I use to read with my PDF library. However the actual file that is stored locally has a name of `foo foo Nov 21, 2018 121604 PM.pdf`

so I have to do this instead

```
'file://' + file.replace(/:/g, "")
```

or it can be done like this

```
'file://' + file.replace(/[|&:;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "file:///storage/emulated/0/somwhere/foo foo Nov 21, 2018 12:16:04 PM.pdf";
        var result = str.split(" ").join("");
        console.log('Result',result);
```

> file:///storage/emulated/0/somwhere/foofooNov21,201812:16:04PM.pdf

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP has a problem with file names that already have a space in the local directory.

Comment: you say ; files without spaces can be opened

Comment: Yah, so removing spaces wouldn't be a problem. OP also tried adding %20 manually and still the same outcome sadly.

Comment: give me static output in this url

Comment: give me excatly  output file:///storage/emulated/0/somwhere/foofooNov21,201812:16:04PM.pdf

Comment: It wont work because `file:///storage/emulated/0/somwhere/foofooNov21,201812:16:04PM.pdf` does not exist

Comment: Sorry but I think you misunderstood my question, my problem wasn't my code but a way to deal with file names with spaces on react native that is locally stored